# How to remove Discourse forum safely from the internet to prevent SEO or Google problems in the main site?

Tags: seo, google-search

I have a Discourse forum that hasn't really taken off, so I want to remove it from the internet. The problem is that it's a subdomain from the main website. So, my question is how to can remove it without affecting the main domain SEO or Google search? I mean, do I have to use redirect? do I have to tell Google something? what's going to happen when the search engine doesn't find the forum anymore?